# Can I travel directly to Croatia on an unused single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, croatia

I am flying from India directly to Zagreb and flying back from Zagreb to India, on an unused single-entry Schengen visa. Will I be allowed entry? I have an Indian passport.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you will need a Croatian visa.

According to Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions:
>   Passengers with a double or multiple entry C visa issued by a Schengen Member State valid for all Schengen Member States and valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
>
> Passengers with a double or multiple entry visa, with limited territorial validity, issued by a Schengen Member State , valid for the territory of all the Member States recognizing the passenger's travel document. The visa must be valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
>
> Passengers with a double or multiple entry C visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Romania valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.

You have a single entry Schengen visa, which will not work for Croatia.